# React SlideToggle plugin expand by props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lot `SlideToggle` blocks which creates from `map`. All is `collapsed` .  How can I expand one of them if I send for example `expandOn` props to one of mapped elemnt?

I find in documentation this

> onMount={({ toggleState, toggle }) => {
>       /* optional event hook */   }}

But I have no idea how it works because documentation have no description.

Answer (score 0):

I get unique duplicated id from server and set it to props and check if duplicated id === id of each el collapsed deny, inside component add this:

```
collapsed={this.props.duplicateID === this.props.id ? undefined : true}
```